# Парсинг JSON ответа при помощи Newtonsoft.JSON

Tags: c#, json

Есть ответ сервера в таком виде (Camunda), хотелось бы выловить id каждого, как сие сотворить даже и не представлю. Помогите пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен.

```
[
{
    "id": "Process_03mhio0:1:ee632e1c-b945-11e9-a37d-14dda953d821",
    "key": "Process_03mhio0",
    "category": "http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn",
    "description": null,
    "name": null,
    "version": 1,
    "resource": "diagram_1.bpmn",
    "deploymentId": "ee5bdb1a-b945-11e9-a37d-14dda953d821",
    "diagram": null,
    "suspended": false,
    "tenantId": null,
    "versionTag": null,
    "historyTimeToLive": null,
    "startableInTasklist": true
},
{
    "id": "invoice:1:505de6c5-b93f-11e9-a37d-14dda953d821",
    "key": "invoice",
    "category": "http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL",
    "description": null,
    "name": "Invoice Receipt",
    "version": 1,
    "resource": "invoice.v1.bpmn",
    "deploymentId": "5053ad91-b93f-11e9-a37d-14dda953d821",
    "diagram": null,
    "suspended": false,
    "tenantId": null,
    "versionTag": "V1.0",
    "historyTimeToLive": 30,
    "startableInTasklist": true
},
{
    "id": "invoice:2:508089ff-b93f-11e9-a37d-14dda953d821",
    "key": "invoice",
    "category": "http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL",
    "description": null,
    "name": "Invoice Receipt",
    "version": 2,
    "resource": "invoice.v2.bpmn",
    "deploymentId": "507df1eb-b93f-11e9-a37d-14dda953d821",
    "diagram": null,
    "suspended": false,
    "tenantId": null,
    "versionTag": "V2.0",
    "historyTimeToLive": 45,
    "startableInTasklist": true
}]
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23%2bjson?tab=Votes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала нужно создать такой класс, чтобы в его объект парсить данные JSON:

```
public class RootObject
{
  public string id { get; set; }
  public string key { get; set; }
  public string category { get; set; }
  public object description { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
  public int version { get; set; }
  public string resource { get; set; }
  public string deploymentId { get; set; }
  public object diagram { get; set; }
  public bool suspended { get; set; }
  public object tenantId { get; set; }
  public string versionTag { get; set; }
  public int? historyTimeToLive { get; set; }
  public bool startableInTasklist { get; set; }
}
```

Далее выполняете десериализацию:

```
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

После этого вся ваша строка id хранится в obj.id. Учитывая её формат, можно разделить строку по двоеточию в массив и выбирать его последний элемент:

```
string[] ID = obj.id.Split(':');
string yourID = ID[ID.Length-1];
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо, правильно понимаю, что их дан массив, а сначит десериализация проходит вот так?
RootObject[] obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(json);

и например, вывести id первого?  MessageBox.Show(obj[1].id);

Comment: @Kellhus, нет, RootObject - класс, вы создаёте его объект. И, как показано в моём ответе, всё, что находится по атрибуту id заносится в качестве строки в свойство объекта obj.id. Обращаясь к obj.id вы получаете всю эту строку (с лишними данными). А уже далее, так как внутри строки разделяется по двоеточию, то вы разбиваете строку obj.id в строковый массив с помощью Split(':'). И последним элементом этого массива будет как раз нужный вам id без лишних данных.

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Comment: @Kellhus, был рад помочь. Отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ в качестве решения.